# Someone managed to write a line of code in my javascript file, how?

Tags: javascript

How can someone physically change a javascript file? It's completely locked down and i've no idea how someone would be able to do this through a web browser.

Rob

Comment: Well, it's clearly not "completely locked down" then. :)  Are you sure it was done through a web browser?  How do you know it wasn't done by someone with access to the server?  Or someone with access to your computer (i.e., modified the file before you uploaded it)?

Comment: Is your FTP password "swordfish" ?

Answer (score 2):

Phished / Hacked your ftp credentials..

Obtained root credentials by exploiting database vulnerabilities etc etc..

Do not focus on the actual altered file (*that is the payload distributor, if the changes were malicious*) but focus on how the gained access on the server..

Comment: Thats can't be it. It's on a webserver thats got about 100 sites and only one sites got the javascript code in it. The site hasn't been updated in over 6 months but the hack happened Friday.

Comment: A lot of trojans these days mine passwords from popular FTP apps like filezilla (which store your passwords in a flat text file). Passwords that can be linked to a domain name will be explioted to spread the trojan further.

Comment: +1 Powertieke. This is the most common source of compromise today. You need to check any machine that has accessed your FTP with multiple anti-virus scanners. And if they find infections or AV has done in the past you need to reinstall that box, because AV is not reliable at removing today's trojans. Also, move to SFTP, it's the 21st Century after all.

Comment: +1, extending on @Powertieke comment, do not use FTP clients that store passwords in plain text.. Either turn filezilla to kiosk mode, so that it does not store passwords, or use another client like WinSCP (for windows)

Comment: @Robert, in regards to your comment, it could very well be that the FTP credentials to this specific domain where compomised by the reasons stated in the comments or otherwise..